# Python and time / datetime

Tags: python, datetime, time, timer

I've recently began work on a Python program as seen in the fragment below.

```
# General Variables
running = False
new = True
timeStart = 0.0
timeElapsed = 0.0

def endProg():
    curses.nocbreak()
    stdscr.keypad(False)
    curses.echo()
    curses.endwin()
    quit()

# Draw
def draw():
    stdscr.addstr(1, 1, ">", curses.color_pair(6))
    stdscr.border()
    if running:
        stdscr.addstr(1, 3, t.strftime( "%H:%M.%S", t.ctime( timeStart - timeElapsed ) ) )

        stdscr.redrawwin()
    stdscr.refresh()

# Calculate
def calc():
    if running:
        timeElapsed = t.clock() - timeStart

stdscr.border()
stdscr.addstr(1, 3, t.strftime( "%H:%M.%S", t.gmtime( t.clock() - t.clock() ) ) )

# Main Loop
while True:
    # Get Input
    kInput = stdscr.getch()

    # Close the program
    if kInput == ord('q'):
        endProg()

    # Stop the current run
    elif kInput == ord('s'):
        stdscr.addstr(1, 3, t.strftime( "%H:%M.%S", t.gmtime( t.clock() - t.clock() ) ) )
        running = False
        new = True

    # Start a run
    elif kInput == ord(' ') and new:
        running = not running
        new = not new
        timeStart = dt.datetime.now()

    # Toggle the timer
    elif kInput == ord('p') and not new:
        timeStart = dt.datetime.now() - timeStart
        running = not running

    calc()
    draw()
```

**My program is a bit between solutions currently**, sorry if something doesn't look right. I'll be more than happy to explain.

I've spent the last several hours reading online about the time and datetime modules for python, trying to figure out how I can use them to accomplish my goals, but however I've tried to implement them it's been no use.

Essentially, I need my program to measure the elapsed time from when a button is pressed and be able to display it in a hour:minute.second format. The subtraction has made it very difficult, having to implement things such as timedelta. From what I have read online there is no way to do what I'm wanting without the datetime module, but it's given me nothing but problems.

Is there an easier solution, does my code have any outstanding errors, and how stupid am I?

Comment: You can use `time.time` to measure elapsed time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ˋtime.time`:

```
import time

star = time.time()
# run long processing...
elapsed = time.time() - start
```

Et voilà !

Answer (score 0):

```
def draw():
    stdscr.border()
    if running:
        stdscr.addstr(1, 1, ">", curses.color_pair(8))
        stdscr.addstr(1, 3, t.strftime( "%H:%M.%S", t.gmtime( timeElapsed ) ) )

    if not running:
        stdscr.addstr(1, 1, ">", curses.color_pair(7))

    stdscr.redrawwin()
    stdscr.refresh()

# Calculate
def calc():
    if running:
        timeElapsed = t.time() - timeStart

stdscr.border()
stdscr.addstr(1, 3, t.strftime( "%H:%M.%S", t.gmtime( t.time() - t.time() ) ) )

# Main Loop
while True:
    # Get Input
    kInput = stdscr.getch()

    # Close the program
    if kInput == ord('q'):
        endProg()

    # Stop the current run
    elif kInput == ord('s'):
        running = False
        new = True

    # Start a run
    elif kInput == ord(' ') and new:
        running = not running
        new = not new
        timeStart = t.time()

    # Toggle the timer
    elif kInput == ord('p') and not new:
        running = not running
        timeStart = t.time() - timeStart

    calc()
    draw()
```

Well, I managed to get rid of all of the errors I was encountering. However, the time displayed is incorrect.

Since we're looking to find the elapsed time, it should start at 0 and increase. My program is starting at 12:21.xx and increasing.

Looking at my code I don't see any errors, but there's obviously one in there somewhere.